# Calling function in forEach with extra parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to substitute an anonymous function call in javascript, for a real function in a forEach.

What I have is something like:

```
whatever: function( importantParam ) {
  array.forEach( function ( val ) {
      if ( val === importantParam ) console.log( "OK" );
  } );
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
whatever: function( importantParam ) {
  array.forEach(this.whatever2,this);
},
whatever2: function( p1, importantParam) {
      if ( p1 === importantParam ) console.log( "OK" );
}
```

So the problem is that I don't really know how to pass the importantParam when i call whatever2 inside forEach, since it takes a function as argument with 2 arguments for they index and the value, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap `whatever2` somehow, e.g. using `.bind`

```
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    obj;
obj = {
    whatever: function (importantParam) {
        array.forEach(this.whatever2.bind(this, importantParam));
    },
    whatever2: function (importantParam, p1) {
        if (p1 === importantParam)
            console.log("OK");
    }
};

obj.whatever(2); // logs OK
```

In ES6 you can clean this up and use arrow functions

```
let obj = {
    whatever(importantParam) {
        array.forEach(x => this.whatever2(x, importantParam));
    },
    whatever2(p1, importantParam) {
        if (p1 === importantParam)
            console.log("OK");
    }
};
```

---

Please note that this example use case you've provided looks like you should actually use `.some` instead of `.forEach` and `return true` where you do the log

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly. I just put an example of how I needed to pass that extra param, I'm not really comparing the values, need it for the whole array, but thanks for that extra tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with another function

```
whatever: function( importantParam ) {
  array.forEach(function(item) {
     this.whatever2(item, importantParam);
  },this);
},
```

or switch the order of arguments and use `bind` to partially apply callback

```
whatever: function( importantParam ) {
  array.forEach(this.whatever2.bind(this, importantParam));
},
whatever2: function(importantParam, p1) {
      if ( p1 === importantParam ) console.log( "OK" );
}
```